# How do I create a curve like Hoss' Hat?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

[image]

I am still learning to 3D models, but I feel this hat can be a good learning experience for someone who wants to go into Game development. The first model I made I finished the curves but they looked like garbage. If any could tell me the best course of action for these hat curves I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

You should begin with less edge loops. Also, use the *Mirror* modifier as the hat seems rather symmetrical. Now you could do it with some extrusions, but maybe it's better to keep concentric circle to have a better topology. So enable the *Proportional Editing* option, drag up some vertices and edges, then inwards. At the end, add a *Solidify* modifier to give thickness, and a *Subdivision* Surface to smooth it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! As I said before I'm pretty new to 3D modeling, and I'm having trouble getting the hat into the shape you had in your photos, or how you got the cuts you used to make the curves. On top of that, I can't figure out how you used the mirror modifier.

Comment: so maybe come back to more basic modeling? There are plenty of tutorials on Youtube. Also, I made the hat that way but there are other ways to do it...